# Apache Django Mod_Wsgi - auto reload

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to auto reload my django app which uses apache + mod_wsgi on my local windows machine.

I'd like to know where do I add this code that's referenced in the following article:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

```
def _restart(path):
    _queue.put(True)
    prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Change detected to \'%s\'.' % (prefix, path)
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Triggering Apache restart.' % prefix
    import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.libhttpd.ap_signal_parent(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html

It tells you exactly where to place the file when using Django. You just need to make the code change that everyone is pointing out to you in the source code reloading documentation section related to Windows. Also read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html

which explains the variations on the first related to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You replace the restart function that is mentioned in the block of code above in the same article.

Comment: You should have some sort of script file that your WSGI application is using as an entry point. That is where the code belongs. If you do not have that file, you will need to look for how to do that before working with auto reload.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code on my server

```
touch site.wsgi
```

and it work. After reload page in browser I get page with changes.
May be it ugly - but simple and no necessary restart apache.

Comment: That only works for daemon mode on UNIX systems, not Windows.

Comment: You can add the touch functionality to your Django views directly. If you're using Linux, make sure the user that you run WSGI/Django with has write access to the file with your entry script. In my case, everything was running as the Apache user, but root had ownership of the script file.

Answer (score 1):

In your Virtual Host config file add this:

```
WSGIScriptReloading On
```

And reload Apache

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

Enjoy!

Reference https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Answer (score 0):

You replace the restart function in the following block of code you find on the page:

```
Monitoring For Code Changes

The use of signals to restart a daemon process could also be employed in a mechanism which automatically detects changes to any Python modules or dependent files. This could be achieved by creating a thread at startup which periodically looks to see if file timestamps have changed and trigger a restart if they have.

Example code for such an automatic restart mechanism which is compatible with how mod_wsgi works is shown below.

import os
import sys
import time
import signal
import threading
import atexit
import Queue

_interval = 1.0
_times = {}
_files = []

_running = False
_queue = Queue.Queue()
_lock = threading.Lock()

def _restart(path):
    _queue.put(True)
    prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Change detected to \'%s\'.' % (prefix, path)
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Triggering process restart.' % prefix
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: I know that but where in the file system is that code? The name of the file, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I test this with **Bitnami DjangoStack** http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack and **Windows XP** installed on **D:\BitNami DjangoStack** and **C:\Documents and Settings\tsurahman\BitNami DjangoStack projects\myproject** as project directory (default install)

<s>as in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Restarting_Apache_Processes, I added</s>

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 1
```

in file **D:\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\conf\django.conf**
see comment by Graham Dumpleton

then I created a file **monitor.py** in my **project directory** with content as in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes and replace the **_restart** method with http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Restarting_Windows_Apache, here is the part of the script

```
....

_running = False
_queue = Queue.Queue()
_lock = threading.Lock()

def _restart(path):
    _queue.put(True)
    prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Change detected to \'%s\'.' % (prefix, path)
    print >> sys.stderr, '%s Triggering Apache restart.' % prefix
    import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.libhttpd.ap_signal_parent(1)

def _modified(path):
    try:

....
```

and in file **D:\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\scripts\django.wsgi**,

```
....

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

import monitor
monitor.start(interval=1.0)
monitor.track(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site.cf'))

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and then restart the Apache server

Comment: You should not be using both MaxRequestPerChild set to 1 and the monitor code at the same time. They are two different techniques. The first will restart on every request. The latter will only restart when a code change is made. If you set the directive, the monitor code becomes pointless as it will restart every request anyway.