# How painful is a django project deployment to a live (staging) site?

Tags: django, web-deployment

I've getting quite fast with a small django project of mine, which I'm developing locally, of course.
But, as I had never worked with django before, I'm not aware of what it implies to upload it and test it on a production server. And I'm quite curious, since I'm very eager to test an early release live.

I know there is this document, which I think it'll be really helpful: http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/

But, are there any details I should take into account before, during and after the deployment?
Any advice or best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble marking only one answer as correct... I'd love if this could be a wiki question. More answers are welcome too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your development/testing environment match your deployment environment as closely as possible. This means using e.g. PostgreSQL and mod_wsgi instead of SQLite and the built-in server. This software is free so there's no reason you can't get your hands on it.

Comment: That advice applies to any and every dev./acceptation environment in any and all languages :)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a good advice. *I am* running on the built-in server and sqlite :D

Comment: +1 - I use the built in server + sqlite for quick prototyping, but I would recommend a matched set of Dev + Staging/Test + Production environments using the "real" software setup for anything else.

Comment: See this question for a way to auto reload on code changes when developing on mod_wsgi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093732/apache-django-mod-wsgi-auto-reload

Answer (score 2):

You might run into problems if you serve your site on a subdirectory of a domain: avoid writing absolute urls by hand, use the [url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag instead.

If you rely on initial data in the database, use [fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

If your server will be used for multiple sites, consider packaging your site with [Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to avoid dependencies conflicts with the other sites.

You should also use the same database system in your dev and production servers to avoid surprises.

Comment: Thanks, great advice too. I'm using url tags. Fixtures... couldn't make it work yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to remove database migration pains, and consider something like [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) or [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/) for deployment if you have a reasonably complex project (or have the time to learn these tools), as they will allow easily reproducible scripted deployments.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot hangs on the change of the database model. Django can add new columns with syncdb, or generate a script to do that, but it will not remove columns and I don't think it will remove foreign key constraints from the database even if they do not apply anymore.

So database migration might be best done scripted, and tested on a copy of the production database or some data set closely resembling production data (the same schema of course).

Comment: How do you add new columns with syncdb ? is it a new feature ?