# why do we need to restart apache after changing some file in django project

Tags: django, apache

I have set up Django on Windows 7 on Apache/mod_wsgi. I need to stop, and then then start the server every time I change any python code. Is there a way to avoid it?

This doesn't happen with javascript/php changes, i.e., no apache restart required for seeing effect of changed code. A push in the right direction would help greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the official documentation about it at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Hi @Graham, i went through the docs and have installed the code under the section #Monitoring_For_Code_Changes. It works. Thank you...

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to restart Apache. Just modify the wsgi file (in an UNIX environment, you could use `touch myfile.wsgi`) and it will be reloaded. In other words, just make sure the last modification date of your wsgi file is updated, even if the file contents itself is not.

P.S. I'm assuming you're running in daemon mode. If you're using embedded mode, then my suggestion won't help you, and I dunno if it's possible to do that at all... See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093732/520779).

**Edit:** sorry, I didn't know daemon mode was [only supported on UNIX](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). In that case, maybe the links in the other question will help, but I can't tell for sure, since I've got no experience with it.

Comment: Well, I read the docs [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes), and indeed, the wsgi is running in embedded mode in Windows 7. So there is no alternative but to restart server every time I make a trivial change. And I don't like the `MaxRequestsPerChild 1` solution as it will restart server for even for php/js files. So, no solution for this in Windows :(

Answer (score 1):

<del>That is because Python code is cached in .pyc files. It is interpreted once, after that cache is used.</del> Sorry, my mistake! Thanks for pointing it out.

If you need to change files often and see the results immediately for development, use Django built in development sever.

It is invoked from the command line using the python interpreter as:
python manage.py runserver

Then you will have the app running @ localhost  on port 8000

Please, go read the docs!

Comment: The code is cached in memory, not in `.pyc` files. You can delete a corresponding `.pyc` file, but you will still need to restart the server to see your changes.

Comment: The pyc files has got nothing to do with it. First off Apache user isn't generally going to have write permission to create pyc files. And second the loaded module is already in memory anyway and so pyc files aren't used on subsequent requests, only at process startup, at which point Python will regenerate them automatically if py file has changed.