# LAMP When i upload php code, but browser is not reflesh until i restart my apache2 services in linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, caching, ubuntu

in my system i install lamp,
i disable my varnish, 
now i update my php code, and when i reflesh my browser, the php code like never change,
after i service apache2 restart, then the code are shown.

the scenario are
at first i submit

```
<?php 
    echo time();

 ?>
```

then i restart apache 2
screen will print timestamp

and then i modify code without restart apache2 services

```
   <?php 
        echo time();
        echo time();

    ?>
```

its still showing one timestamp,by right it should display 2 time stamp.

and everytime i reflesh the timestamp are changing ,so this is not a varnish issue.

but after i service apache2 restart, then 2 timestamp will show....

in my AWS ubuntu i do not hav opcache, and im using php 5.3.10

may i know how to disable this caching mechanism?
or anything i miss

some other case in mamp, it refer to something call opcache, but i did not use any or this.
FYI i install apc and memcache, but should not causing this problem, because i got another server also install the same thing.

Anyone please help , thanks

Comment: Is it because of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480043/why-do-we-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-some-file-in-django-project

Answer (score 0):

It's probably opcode cache.

```
   <?php 
        ini_set('wincache.ocenabled', false); //<-- this desactivate it. (you may as well edit your php.ini file to edit this option.

        echo time();
    ?>
```

If that doesn't work, a hack consists in calling your script passing a random parameter to it :

http://server.com/script.php?t=1

then update your code, and if you call :

http://server.com/script.php?t=2

The result should be updated.